# Получить значение анимированного стикера aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я знаю как кинуть кубик(игральную кость) и считать значение, которое выпало, но возможно ли кинуть другие анимированные стикеры и считать их значение?
Вот код для броска кубика

```
result: Message = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id)
print(result.dice.value)
```

А мне нужно бросить такие стикеры как: ,,⚽,,. Возможно ли это сделать? Если да, то как?

Comment: Почему бы не [глянуть](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/message.html#aiogram.types.message.Message.answer_dice), [документацию](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/send_dice.html) (ссылок две ;) ), это же так сложно что требует отдельного вопроса на стэке?

Comment: я смотрел документацию,но не понял как мне отправлять смайлы кроме кубика,если написать просто result: Message = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id) , то будет кидаться кубик, а как кинуть другой смайл, я не понял.

Comment: Если вы смотрели обе приведенные ссылки - то у меня для вас плохие новости... бросайте программирование :)

Answer (score 1):

ладно, даже отвечу на это

`from aiogram.types.dice import DiceEmoji`

`bot.send_dice(chat_id, emoji=DiceEmoji.DICE/DART etc.)`

Answer (score 0):

`result: Message = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, emoji='')` Я не до конца прочитал документацию.